# How to iterate over a list using a Regex

Tags: string-manipulation, regular-expressions

I need to replace all "Nx" with "N0x" in the following, but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
data = {"N1 G01 X35 Y51 Z00", "N2 G01 X34 Y50 Z00", "N3 G01 X33 Y50 Z00", 
"N4 G01 X32 Y50 Z00", "N5 G01 X31 Y50 Z00", "N6 G01 X30 Y50 Z00", "N7 
G01 X29 Y50 Z00", "N8 G01 X28 Y50 Z00", "N9 G01 X27 Y50 Z00", "N10 
N00 G98 X00 Y00 Z-30", "N11 G01 X26 Y49 Z00", "N12 G01 X25 Y49 Z00", 
"N13 G01 X24 Y49 Z00"}
```

So far, I have tried several combinations of Regular Expressions and StringReplace, to no avail.

Comment: Why not `StringReplace[#, "N" -> "N0"] & /@ data`?

Comment: I only need to insert the 0 after N's that have a single integer following it. :)

Comment: `(StringReplace[#, 
    "N" ~~ d : DigitCharacter ~~ WordBoundary :> "N0" <> d]) & /@ data`

Answer (score 5):

The following is a string expression which I think does what you describe:

```
StringReplace[data, 
  "N" ~~ d : DigitCharacter ~~ x : Except[DigitCharacter] :> 
  "N0" <> d <> x]
```

Note that `StringReplace` does automatically map onto lists of strings (which is documented), so you don't need to `Map` it onto the list of strings `data`.

If you prefer regular expressions here is the same expressed with regular expressions:

```
StringReplace[data, RegularExpression["N(\\d)([^\\d])"] :> "N0$1$2"]
```

These do both work for your example data, but won't replace when the pattern is at the end of a string, like in `"N1 N2 G01 X35 Y51 N3"`, if you want to also handle those, that can be either achieved with an additional rule:

```
StringReplace[data, {
  "N" ~~ d : DigitCharacter ~~ x : Except[DigitCharacter] :> 
  "N0" <> d <> x,
  "N" ~~ d : DigitCharacter ~~ EndOfString :> "N0" <> d
}]

StringReplace[data, {
  RegularExpression["N(\\d)([^\\d])"] :> "N0$1$2",
  RegularExpression["N(\\d)$"] :> "N0$1"
}]
```

or with a slightly more complicated pattern:

```
StringReplace[data, 
  "N" ~~ d:DigitCharacter ~~ x:(Except[DigitCharacter] | EndOfString) :> 
  "N0" <> d <> x]

StringReplace[data,RegularExpression["N(\\d)([^\\d]|$)"] :> "N0$1$2"]
```